# Term for faking something in a movie related to set or lighting

Tags: effects, terminology

So, I was under the incorrect assumption that the term "gaffe" referred to creating something that just looks close enough to pass on screen. I'm certain I heard this term used for barnum and bailey's "mermaid" creation.  Now I want to know what the correct term for this is... I understand that this is technically what you would call special effects. but I'm looking more for the term when it is not a custom made "prop" but a slopped together prop that only looks good when not closely scrutinized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Props generally fall into two categories; "Hero" (those that can stand close scrutiny, often with working parts and lights) and "Stunt"

> **Stunt Version**
>
> ***A “stunt” version of a prop is typically a low-quality version of a
>   “hero” or detailed prop so that the “hero” version is neither
>   destroyed nor causes harm to the people involved with the stunt.*** For
>   instance, in the fight scene between Kara Thrace and a Number Six in
>   “Kobol’s Last Gleaming, Part II,” a stunt version of the Arrow of
>   Apollo (made of rubber) was used in that scene. There were two
>   versions of metal and two of rubber made. Stunt versions of props are
>   typically of rubber. Stunt versions of costumes will be the same
>   quality, though specifically marked “stunt”. They may be old versions
>   of the costume, used by the main actor and then given for use by the
>   stunt actor, or they may be new versions, specifically tailored for a
>   stunt actor.
>
> <sub><sup>http://www.propworx.com/auctions/auction-terminology/</sup></sub>

If you simply mean a prop that has been cobbled together from parts, you may be looking for a word like "[fudged](http://www.gbfans.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=26637)" or "[throwaway](https://m.reddit.com/comments/261oek)"

Comment: I like fudged. I mostly wanted a term for software development. where the user is really the "audience" in film making terms, and they don't care if the site works because of awesome code, or 50000 humans are just hand editing all the content 24/7, so I wanted to be able to say things like "the software fudged, automation, the users didn't care, because it still worked"

Comment: @Mr.Manager - For messily fixed software you want either ["kludge"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) or "a hack"